# Dealing with commas and apostrophes when importing CSV files

Tags: excel, vba, csv, file, delimiter

I'm uploading product information from CSV files, but the descriptions often have commas or single quotes in them, causing some of them to be incomplete after importing.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to deal with this in either Excel (2010) or VBA?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

You import the data, mark the first column.

Then "Data" > "Text to Columns" > "Delimited" > "Next"

Choose "Comma" AND/OR "Other" and write down the single quote

Next > Finish

Have you tried it? I always deal like that with every .csv file that I receive.

**Option 2**

Opening the .csv file using text editor and inserting the following line at the beginning of the file will explicitly inform Excel what delimiter is used. Write down comma or single quote sign after the `=`, instead of the semicolon.

`sep=;`

This line is not seen when the file is opened using Excel.